# Decribe the $S^2$ fibration over $S^2$ that gives $\mathbf{CP}^2\#\overline{\mathbf{CP}}^2$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, 4-manifolds

According to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53399/spaces-with-same-homotopy-and-homology-groups-that-are-not-homotopy-equivalent) MO post, there is two possible $S^2$ fibration over $S^2$. One is obviously $S^2\times S^2$, another one is the connected sum of two copies of $\mathbf {CP}^2$ with different orientations. Can someone explicitly describe the $S^2$ fibration over $S^2$ that gives $\mathbf{CP}^2\#\overline{\mathbf{CP}}^2$?

Comment: What qualifies as a "description"?  The other $S^2$-bundle over $S^2$ is the one whose monodromy is the non-trivial element of $\pi_1 SO_3 \simeq \mathbb Z_2$.

Comment: I don't see how this description shows the total space is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^{2} \# \bar{\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}}^{2}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^{2} \# \bar{\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}}^{2}$ is the blow-up of $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^{2}$ at a point. Let $A$ be an affine chart of $ \mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^{2}$ and $L_{\infty} = \mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^{2} \setminus A$ be the line at infinity.

Let $p$ be the origin in $A$. Consider the set of all (projective) lines through $p \in \mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^{2}$, then they cover $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^{2}$ and only intersect pair-wise at $p$. Blowing up $p$ "seperates" all of these lines and creates a $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^{1}$-bundle structure; the fibres being strict transforms of lines through $p$. The base can also be identified with $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^{1}$ since each of the lines containing $p$ intersects the line $L_{\infty}$ at a unique point.

Answer (score 5):

Cheeger described in "[Some examples of manifolds with nonnegative curvature](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214431964)" the connected sum $\mathbb C\mathbb P^n\#\overline{\mathbb C\mathbb P^n}$ as a biquotient: Take $(S^{2n-1}\times S^2)/S^1$, where $S^1$ is acting freely on $S^{2n-1}$ and by rotations on $S^2$. This is the associated bundle to the principal fibration $S^1\to S^{2n-1}\to\mathbb C\mathbb P^n$ with fiber $S^2$. See Example 3 in Cheeger's article, why the above quotient is $\mathbb C\mathbb P^n\#\overline{\mathbb C\mathbb P^n}$.